# LDAP connection through proxy

Tags: iptables, routing, proxy, ldap

I have the following infrastructure:

LDAP (Externe network) - SQUID - HOST1,HOST2,HOST3...

All of them are Ubuntu Server.

I need to be able to make LDAPS requests from the hosts through port 636, however I can't reach the LDAP server from them.

I have tried:

- Forward the ldaps requests in a port based acl through squid (didn't work since squid is specifically oriented to http trafic)
- Applying static routes directly over the hosts (didn't work because I can't add any other gateway to my already existent interfaces.
- Forwarding with iptables, didn't work because I don't find the way to get back the answer from LDAP server only to the host which has previously made the request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved by applying the following iptables NAT rule in the intermediate server (the one who has the Squid):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s LOCAL_HOSTS_NETWORK_ADDRESS -j MASQUERADE -d LDAP_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS -p tcp --dport 636
```